# How to align EXPLICIT_ACCESS properly with jedi-winutils for SetEntriesInAclA?

Tags: delphi, winapi, acl, freepascal, memory-alignment

I am trying to create a new ACL from an array of `EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A` in Free Pascal using `SetEntriesInAclA`, but I keep getting error code 87 (Invalid Parameter) from `SetEntriesInAclA` with
the following code:

```pascal
uses
  sysutils,
  JwaWinNT,
  JwaAclApi,
  JwaAccCtrl,
  JwaSDDL,
  jwawinbase,
  jwawinsta,
  jwawintype,
  jwawinerror; 

function SetupAccess(owner: jwawinnt.PSID; var acl: jwawinnt.PACL): bool;
  const
    EA_COUNT = 3;
  var
    sidAuthWorld: jwawinnt.SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY;
    sidAuthNT: jwawinnt.SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY;
    everyoneSID: jwawinnt.PSID;
    adminSID: jwawinnt.PSID;
    ea: Array[0..(EA_COUNT-1)] of jwaaccctrl.EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A;
    status: jwawintype.DWORD;
  begin
    try
      begin
        WriteLn(IntToStr(SizeOf(jwaaccctrl.EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A)));
        sidAuthWorld := jwawinnt.SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
        sidAuthNT := jwawinnt.SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

        if not (jwawinbase.AllocateAndInitializeSid(@sidAuthWorld, 1, jwawinnt.SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, everyoneSID)
          and AllocateAndInitializeSid(@sidAuthNT, 2, jwawinnt.SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
          jwawinnt.DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, adminSID)) then
        begin
          WriteLn('Could not allocate SIDs: ' + SysErrorMessage(getLastError()));
          Result := false;
        end
        else
        begin
          jwawinbase.ZeroMemory(@ea, EA_COUNT * sizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A));

          ea[0].grfAccessPermissions := GENERIC_ALL;
          ea[0].grfAccessMode := DENY_ACCESS;
          ea[0].grfInheritance := NO_INHERITANCE;
          ea[0].Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation := NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE;
          ea[0].Trustee.pMultipleTrustee := nil;
          ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm := TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
          ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType := TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
          ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName := pointer(everyoneSID);

          ea[1].grfAccessPermissions := GENERIC_ALL;
          ea[1].grfAccessMode := SET_ACCESS;
          ea[1].grfInheritance := NO_INHERITANCE;
          ea[1].Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation := NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE;
          ea[1].Trustee.pMultipleTrustee := nil;
          ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeForm := TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
          ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeType := TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
          ea[1].Trustee.ptstrName := pointer(adminSID);

          ea[2].grfAccessPermissions := GENERIC_ALL;
          ea[2].grfAccessMode := SET_ACCESS;
          ea[2].grfInheritance := NO_INHERITANCE;
          ea[2].Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation := NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE;
          ea[2].Trustee.pMultipleTrustee := nil;
          ea[2].Trustee.TrusteeForm := TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
          ea[2].Trustee.TrusteeType := TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
          ea[2].Trustee.ptstrName := pointer(owner);

          status := jwaaclapi.SetEntriesInAclA(2, @ea, nil, acl);
          if status = ERROR_SUCCESS then
            Result := true
          else
          begin
            WriteLn('Error in SetEntriesInAcl: ' + IntToStr(status));
            Result := false;
          end;
        end;
      end
    finally
      If Assigned(everyoneSID) then
        jwawinbase.FreeSID(everyoneSID);
      If Assigned(adminSID) then
        jwawinbase.FreeSID(adminSID);
    end
  end;
```

While googling the issue, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960007/reasons-for-setentriesinacl-error-87-in-msdn-sample), which hinted that the issue is probably related to the alignment of the `EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A` record.

And sure enough `WriteLn(IntToStr(SizeOf(jwaaccctrl.EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A)));` shows, that it is of size 20. This is because jedi declares the struct as `packed`. From the linked question I gather that `EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A` should
be of size 24, but after testing this in C++, it actually seems to be 32.

I also tried copying the `EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A` and `TRUSTEE_A` structs to my
unit and removing the `packed` keyword. This yielded structures of size 24,
but still the same error.

In conclusion: Can I make above code work with jedi or is it a bug/oversight in jedi?

Also note that I am cross compiling from x64 to x86 using Lazarus 2.0.4 and FPC 3.0.4.

Comment: Tried to redefine the `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` structure. And replace the `enum` type with `DWORD`.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT This actually works, which suggests, that setting minimum enum size to 4 would resolve the issue. I wonder why FPC ignores both the `MINENUMSIZE` directive and the `-CPPACKENUM=4` command line option.

Comment: The _actual_ problem seems to be that JwaAccCtrl uses enum size 1 which I can't influence at all. I don't think this is intended, but fpc 3.0.4 ships like this.

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=36368) for FPC, lets see where this leads.

Comment: I found that this report has been marked as resolved. Could you organize an answer here and mark yourself to help people who have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differently from what I expected, the problem was not related to record-alignment, but to the size of the enums in the record. The `EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A` record and its sub record have a total of 8 fields which are all expected to be 4 bytes big by WinApi (on 32-bit), resulting in a total size of 32 bytes (on 32-bit). On 64-bit, some fields are bigger, but enum size still should be 4. If FPC's enum size is not 4 then this assumption is violated and WinApi returns error code 87.

The code I provided is correct and should work in theory. The issue was created by an error in the version of Jedi provided by FPC. There, the Enum size was erroneously reset back to 1 by an include in `JediApiLib.inc`. This has been fixed in FPC trunk/Revision 43608 and will hopefully be included in the next release. You can check out the bug report [here](https://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=36368).

Until then there is a workaround which annoyingly involves redefining the used records, as you can simply replace all Enums with `DWORD`s to force the correct size. The new types would look like this:

```pascal
type
  TRUSTEE_FIX = packed record
    pMultipleTrustee: Pointer;
    MultipleTrusteeOperation: DWORD;
    TrusteeForm: DWORD;
    TrusteeType: DWORD;
    ptstrName: LPSTR;
  end;

  EXPLICIT_ACCESS_FIX = packed record
    grfAccessPermissions: DWORD;
    grfAccessMode: DWORD;
    grfInheritance: DWORD;
    Trustee: TRUSTEE_FIX;
  end;
```

Of course, you'll need to convert the Enum values to `DWORD` when filling an `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` record like here for example:

```pascal
jwawinbase.ZeroMemory(@ea, EA_COUNT * sizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS_FIX));

ea[0].grfAccessPermissions := GENERIC_ALL;
ea[0].grfAccessMode := DWORD(DENY_ACCESS);
ea[0].grfInheritance := NO_INHERITANCE;
ea[0].Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation := DWORD(NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE);
ea[0].Trustee.pMultipleTrustee := nil;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm := DWORD(TRUSTEE_IS_SID);
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType := DWORD(TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP);
ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName := pointer(everyoneSID);

status := jwaaclapi.SetEntriesInAclA(EA_COUNT, @ea, nil, acl);
```

Answer (score 3):

For 32 bit, the EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A struct should be 32 bytes.
The record was likely packed because it contains a union.
I tested this using Jedi ApiLib in Delphi it returns the correct size:

```
program SizeTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  JwaAccCtrl;

begin
  WriteLn(Format('EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A size: %d', [SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS_A)]));
```

Output:

[image: Output]

In Delphi {$MINENUMSIZE 4} is used to force enum to 4 bytes (as in C), perhaps you need to set this in [Lazarus/FPC](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu59.html)?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Lazarus/FPC. I also tried using different compiler directives like `CODEALIGN`, `ALIGN`, `PACKRECORD` and also, like you suggested, `MINENUMSIZE`. Also setting `{$MODE DELPHI}` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Compiler directives only influence the current unit, the problem is, that Jedi uses enum size 1 for some reason in my case.

Comment: All Jwa units by default include `JediAPILib.inc` which is based on `jedi.inc` and it starts with `{$A+} {record alignment on 4 byte boundaries}` and `{$Z4} {enum size is 4 bytes}`